# Unable to set GOPATH in elementary os loki

Tags: bash, go, elementary-os

**Input :**

```
echo "GOPATH=/home/chawat/Programming/GoWorkspace" >> ~/.bashrc

echo "export GOPATH" >> ~/.bashrc

echo "PATH=\$PATH:\$GOPATH/bin" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

**Output:**

```
bash: /home/chawat/.bashrc: line 171: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

bash: /home/chawat/.bashrc: line 171: `esacGOPATH=/home/chawat/Programming/GoWorkspace'
```

plz help me whats wrong?

Comment: can you tell us the desired behaviour?

Comment: I was trying to set GOPATH as per instructions from this site https://larry-price.com/blog/2013/12/15/setting-up-a-go-environment-in-ubuntu-12-dot-04

Comment: but after the input commands , I was expecting the gopath to be set to the desired location... but it wasnt and I am getting this output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `.bashrc` was not terminated by a newline before you ran those commands. Look at the end of the file in a text editor and make sure that `GOPATH=/home/chawat/Programming/GoWorkspace` starts on a line of its own.